# Como mudar o background Color de um DIV com Class e Id defnidos?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Estou tendo um problema no meu código Javascript, não consigo alterar o background de uma div, sendo que eu defini ela em CSS com uma classe e sua cor é branco.

```js
function escolha(id){
 if(document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor=="#FFFFFF"){
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="#ccf2ff";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor=="FFFFFF"
 }
}
```

```css
.bc{
 float:left;
 width:150px;
 height:200px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="bc" id="b1" onclick="escolha(this.id)">
   <img src="images/af.jpg" height="150" width="100"> 
   <p>ABUBUBUB</p>     
  </div>
```

O comando é simples: Clicou na div ela muda de cor, clicou de novo ela volta a ser branca.

Espero atenciosamente por ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Três problemas:

- quando defines o style no CSS o atributo `.style` está vazio pois ele é aplicado ao elemento do DOM. Tens de usar `window.getComputedStyle`.
- quando defines o style no CSS o browser dá-te RGBs numéricos (não tenho a certeza se todos os browsers se comportam dessa maneira)
- a sintaxe em `style.backgroundColor=="FFFFFF"` está errada, deve ser `==` e `#` no código da cor

Sugestão:

```js
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  // de https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627747/2256325
  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

  function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function escolha(el) {
  var style = el.style.backgroundColor;
  style = style && rgb2hex(el.style.backgroundColor);
  if (!style || style == '#ffffff') {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#ccf2ff";
  } else {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"
  }
}
```

```css
.bc {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bc" id="b1" onclick="escolha(this)">
  <img src="images/af.jpg" height="150" width="100">
  <p>ABUBUBUB</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Meu Deus, tinha um terceiro bug, botei um == em vez de =, funcionou cara, eu nem tinha percebido, deve ser o sono, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RuyNeto editei, faltava também um `#` e juntei outra ideia.

Comment: Entendi seu acréscimo, retorna o código bonitinho, obrigado cara, sério mesmo, a essa hora me ajudar.